# getting duplicate values in jsonb query posgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, unnest

In table I have used jsonb to store multiple values in json array. now i want to write a query where day is monday. [{'day':'monday','time':"8 am"},{'day':'tuesday','time':"8 am"}{'day':'monday','time':"11 am"},{'day':'friday','time':"8 am"}]

Query:

```
SELECT  array_to_json(array_agg(j))
FROM demo  t, jsonb_array_elements(t.di_item ) j
WHERE j->>'day' = 'monday'
```

Result:

```
[{'day':'monday','time':"8 am"},{'day':'monday','time':"11 am"},{'day':'monday','time':"8 
am"},{'day':'monday','time':"11 am"}]
```

Expected:

```
[{'day':'monday','time':"8 am"},{'day':'monday','time':"11 am"}]
```

One value getting two times.

Comment: You are getting the result you are asking for, those objects that have a `day = monday`. You will need to be more specific about how you want to qualify the query to return one instance of `monday`.

Answer (score 0):

First: no need to aggregate the json objects as an array, and then convert it to a json array, you can use `json[b]_agg()` directly. Then: use `distinct` to avoid duplicates.

```
SELECT  jsonb_agg(distinct j)
FROM demo  t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.di_item) j
WHERE j->>'day' = 'monday'
```